# The volume in docker-compose is not synchronized between the container and the host

Tags: docker-compose

Please tell me what am I doing wrong.
I simplified everything to a minimum, but could not solve the problem of volume synchronization between the container and the host, in either direction

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN go mod tidy
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    command: go run ./main.go
```

Docker version 25.0.3, build 4debf41
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c

docker inspect <container> contains the following fragments

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/home/xxxx/projects/api-example",
                "Destination": "/usr/src/app",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
```

```
 "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/home/xxxx/projects/api-example:/usr/src/app:rw"
            ],
```

I can connect to the container and create a text file in it, but it is not visible on the host machine,
also when creating a text file on the host machine I don't see it in the container.

I restarted the docker service,
deleted volumes, containers, images, but did not achieve any results,

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't reproduce.